# Remove "sysadmin@thingsboard.org'" from the database to install Thingsboard

Tags: database, installation, thingsboard

I am trying to install Thingsboard on Windows 10. But I get the error: "org.thingsboard.server.dao.exception.DataValidationException: User with email 'sysadmin@thingsboard.org'  already present in database!"

Would anyone please help me to resolve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had same problem and fixed it with this method:
Delete thingsboard folder and registry keys.
Install again.

Answer (score 1):

Thingsboard uses `/usr/share/thingsboard/data/.firstLaunch` file to see if installation is needed on startup. If `.firstLaunch` file exists, Thingsboard will just start, but if does not exist, Thingsboard will try to install and populate database.

If you already have Thingsboard database configured, just create empty `.firstLaunch` file in `/usr/share/thingsboard/data` directory and error will not occur anymore.

Check this link to see how it works: https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/99afad3f6fa9e27fbf81c531ca3917b597df1e24/msa/tb/docker/start-tb.sh#L27

Answer (score 0):

There is "data" directory where you extracted thingsboard and installed.
so deleted DB file/dir and all the non .sql files from there.
Now reinstall it.

it will work surely.